# i have displayed a JDialog using JOptionPane.showOptionDialog , can someone tell me how to set it inVisible or Dispose it?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, joptionpane

i have displyed this `JDialog` , and have passed an Object which is a `JPanel` on it , thus my `JDialog` displays my `JPanel` on it when Invoked as required.
and on this `JPanel` I have a `JButton`, on pressing i want some operations to happen which i have written in it's `ActionListener` and in the end i have to dispose that `JDialog`, but i have no clue how to do it !!

This s my `JDialog` Statement and help me with HOW TO EVEN REMOVE AN ICON from `JDialog` as even after keeping the ICON PARAMETER NULL it displays the ICON.

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "SELECT ITEM AND THEN EDIT THE DETAILS.", 
    "EDIT ITEM DETAILS", int1, int2 , null, objEditMorePane, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOptionPane closes its dialog when its `value` property changes.  So, you can obtain the parent JOptionPane and set its value to close the window:

```
JOptionPane optionPane = (JOptionPane)
    SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JOptionPane.class, button);
optionPane.setValue(JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
```

If the window wasn't created by JOptionPane, you can use the `getTopLevelAncestor` method of JComponent to obtain the parent window:

```
Window window = (Window) button.getTopLevelAncestor();
window.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to keep a reference to the dialog if you want to close it yourself. See [the Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup) on custom `Dialog`s. The constructor you're using also puts in an icon by default; if you make your own dialog, you can control that part too.

Comment: can u give a small example here , i have no clue what to use as a reference here !!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to make it a JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE. That is what you need to put instead of whatever int2 is. I was going to link you to the tutorial but Space Pope already did that. You don't need to create a custom dialog to change the default icon, just change the message type to a plain message. The tutorial covers all this stuff.

Comment: hey buddy , your JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE really solved my icon issue !

Comment: if you could help me with HOW DO I SET A REFERENCE , so that i can dispose/set it InVisible it on button's action .